# Why doesn't this jQuery-mobile CSS only display one list or fail?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

My jQuery-mobile CSS doesn't work.  It works when I have no `var`, but then it shows only one list and I have multiple to show.

Relevant code:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json) {
    var la = "";
    $.each(json.post,function(i,post) {   
        la += "<li><a id='id' class='chat' href='#'><img src='afbeelding'><h2>naam</h2><p>Komt nog</p></a></li>";   
    });
    $("ul:jqmData(role='listview')").append(la);
});
```

Comment: Use `$('data-role=listview').listview().listview('refresh')` or `$('data-role=listview').listview('refresh')` after you append the items.

Comment: @Omar Please post that as an answer so that this question may help others. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, I'm glad I've been of help.

Answer (score 0):

To enhance markup of dynamically add list items use the below.

```
$('[data-role=listview]').listview().listview('refresh');

$('[data-role=listview]').listview('refresh');
```

after you append the items.